# Start reading and writing on specific line on CSV with Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
COL_A,COL_B
12345,A=1$B=2$C=3$
```

How do I read that file and wrote it back to a new file but just the second row (line)? 
I want the output file to contain:

```
12345,A=1$B=2$C=3$
```

Thanks!

Comment: is there a comma between COL_B and 12345?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following reads your csv, extracts the second row, then writes that second row to another file.

```
with open('file.csv') as file:
    second_line = list(file)[1]

with open('out.csv', mode = 'w') as file:
    file.write(second_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
outfile = open(outfilename,"w")
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
       print >> outfile , line.split()[-1]
outfile.close()
```

as long as the lines actually look like the line you posted in the OP