# read specific line in csv file , python

Tags: python, csv, reader

In an `CSV` file with python we can read all the file line by line or row by row , I want to read specific line (line number 24 example ) without reading all the file and all the lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start reading and writing on specific line on CSV with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618207/start-reading-and-writing-on-specific-line-on-csv-with-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [linecache.getline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html#linecache.getline):

**linecache.getline(filename, lineno[, module_globals])**

> Get line lineno from file named filename. This function will never raise an exception — it will return '' on errors (the terminating newline character will be included for lines that are found).

```
import linecache


line = linecache.getline("foo.csv",24)
```

Or use the [consume recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) from itertools to move the pointer:

```
import collections
from itertools import islice

def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)

with open("foo.csv") as f:
    consume(f,23)
    line = next(f)
```

Comment: @xtofl, a file object is its own iterator, when you `for line in f:...`, next is repeatedly called

Comment: and to start the reading from a specific line and not from the beginning? it workwith simply consume(f,X) and increment the X each time (initialize the X on the desired position), thanks for your usefull answer :)

Comment: @user3967257, use the consume recipe if you want to start from a certain line, the second arg to consume is the amount of lines to consume then just `for line in f...` to read the rest of the lines.

Comment: this is what I mean
for i in range(X,limit):
 consume(f,i)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can leverage the `nrows` and `skiprows` argument in pandas

```
line_number = 30
pd.read_csv('big.csv.gz', sep = "\t", nrows = 1, skiprows = line_number - 1)
```

remember `skiprows` can be a list so if you need the header use

```
pd.read_csv('big.csv.gz', sep = "\t", nrows = 1, skiprows = list(range(1, line_number - 1)))
```