# Trying to read the first line of CSV file returns ['/']

Tags: python, csv

I have uploaded a CSV file through Django and I trying to read the first line of it. The file is stored on the server in

```
/tmp/csv_file/test.csv
```

The file looks like this:

```
column_1,column_2,column_3
2175,294,Nuristan
2179,299,Sar-e-Pul
```

I am trying to get the headings of the file like:

```
absolute_base_file = '/tmp/csv_file/test.csv'
csv_reader = csv.reader(absolute_base_file)
csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
print csv_headings
```

I only get this in return:

```
['/']
```

**EDITED**

The permissions of the CSV file are:

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

Which should be ok.

**EDITED AGAIN**

Based on the recommendations and the help of @EdChum and @Moses Koledoye

I have checked if the file is read correctly using:

```
print (os.stat(absolute_base_file).st_size) # returns 64
```

Then I tried to see if seek(0) and csvfile.read(1) return a single printable character.

```
   print csvfile.seek(0) returns None
   print csvfile.read(1) returns 'c'
```

Then I thought perhaps there is a particular issue with next() function and I tried an alternative:

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
for row in csv_reader:   
   print ("csv_reader")
```

Again this didn't work.

Comment: can you post a link to csv file for me to download and try

Comment: that loads fine for me: `['id', ' name', ' date']
first row:  ['0', ' name', ' 2009-01-01']` I'm not sure what else to suggest here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You passed a string instead of a file object which is why you get the slash, change to this:

```
with open (absolute_base_file) as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

See this working:

```
In [5]:
import csv
with open (r'c:\data\csv_test.csv') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
    print (csv_headings)

['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']
```

To successively access each row call `next`:

```
In [7]:
import csv
with open (r'c:\data\csv_test.csv') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
    print (csv_headings)
    first_row = next(csv_reader)
    print( 'first row: ', first_row)


['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']
first row:  ['2175', '294', 'Nuristan']
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. But how can I access the first row of the CSV then?

Comment: call `next` again for arbitrary row see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964244/read-specific-line-in-csv-file-python

Comment: Hmm. I still can not make it work. Everything works till: csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)  But when I try to access the csv_reader as:  next(csv_reader) I get nothing back.

Comment: Check if the file is being read correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507808/python-how-to-check-file-empty-or-not

Comment: print (os.stat(absolute_base_file).st_size) returns 64

Comment: I wonder if this:  with open (absolute_base_file, 'rb') as csvfile:  is equivalent to what you suggested: with open (r'c:\data\csv_test.csv') as csvfile:

Comment: OK and does `seek(0)` and `csvfile.read(1)` return a single char that is printable?

Comment: print csvfile.seek(0) returns None and print csvfile.read(1) returns 'c'

Comment: Well if you can read it fine then the above should work, are you saying that calling `next` and printing whatever is returned doesn't work?

Comment: Well I thought that's the case but then I tried without next() as: csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                    for row in csv_reader:
                        print ("csv_reader")  Still no response.

Comment: Does your csv file not contain carriage returns? i.e. it's all on a single line? Open it in a text editor to check. Also edit your question with the updated attempts and errors so the formatting isn't lost

Comment: Hmm. This must be related. I see that when I try this: vim test.csv I get: id, name, date^M0, name, 2009-01-01^M1, another name, 2009-02-01

Comment: that is a carriage return `\r` can you add `'rb'` as a param to `open`

Comment: I had 'rb' since the beginning: with open(absolute_base_file, 'rb') as csvfile:

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a file object to your `csv.reader` not a string literal.

```
absolute_base_file = open(r'/tmp/csv_file/test.csv') # notice open
csv_reader = csv.reader(absolute_base_file)
csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
print csv_headings
```

Comment: The first part of it, works but when trying to get the headings (csv_headings) then I get an error.

Comment: I think it must not recognize the next() function. I use python 2.7. The thing is the whole code is in a try...except so it just doesn't execute it.

Comment: problem with your path?

Comment: I think no. This is what I get back when I print (csv_reader): <_csv.reader object at 0x2f466e0>   I think this implies its accessible.

Comment: Try `csv_reader.next()` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.next). Not sure if that changes anything though.

Comment: Nope. Same thing. I wonder if this is related with permissions. Shouldn't be Read permissions enough?